# Is there a way to dynamically group values of a an array/list in python based on their decimal places?

Tags: python, arrays, list, group-by, mean

I have the following an 1D array:

```
B = [8.55905955, 8.63646974, 21.7694643, 21,87843119, 21.92463355]
```

Based on this array I want to have a new array that consists only of the mean of similar values. For the array shown above, it should lead to a new array like:

```
B_new = [8.598, 21.858]
```

What should be considered:

The total number of values in B is variable. The number of values which should be grouped are variable (could be 2, 3, 4, 5, or even only one). The threshold for values considered in one group should be based on the distance from between consecutive values, e.g., [8.5, 8.7, 8.8] should be one group and [8.5, 8.7, 9.9, 10.2] should lead to two groups because the difference between 8.7  and 9.9 is greater than 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from more_itertools import split_when
from statistics import mean

B = [8.55905955, 8.63646974, 21.7694643, 21.87843119, 21.92463355]

B_new = [*map(mean, split_when(B, lambda x, y: y - x > 1))]
```

Comment: Might wanna mention that this requires an extra package to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, step-by-step generator function:

```
def chunk_avg(array, min_gap=1):
    chunk = []
    for n in array:
        if chunk and chunk[-1] + min_gap < n:
            yield sum(chunk) / len(chunk)
            chunk.clear()
        chunk.append(n)
    if chunk:
        yield sum(chunk) / len(chunk)

list(chunk_avg([8.55905955, 8.63646974, 21.7694643, 21.87843119, 21.92463355]))
# [8.597764645000002, 21.857509679999996]
list(chunk_avg([8.5, 8.7, 9.9, 10.2]))
# [8.6, 10.05]
```